Can't install Kubuntu 24.04 or Lubuntu 24.04 in encrypted partition
I tried installing these several times, but the same error keeps occurring every time. During installation, I selected manual partitioning, created an ext4 partition, checked the encrypt box, entered a passphrase, selected / as mount point, and proceeded with the installation. But after reboot when it asks for the encryption passphrase, and the passphrase is entered, it immediately shows an error like this:
error: Invalid passphrase.
error: disk 'cryptouuid/abc123...' not found.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>

I am already using an encrypted installation of Lubuntu 22.04 as my main OS, and when I mistype the passphrase sometimes, it takes a few seconds before showing an error. But this time with 24.04, the error is almost instant without any delay, which makes me assume it is not even trying to decrypt.
Yes, I made sure the passphrase is correct. And I also made sure to create extra partitions when it was necessary (e.g. 8 MB unformatted when I tried with BIOS, or 300 MB fat32 when it was with UEFI, etc). I even tried good old MBR with no extra partition. I even tried selecting btrfs instead of ext4. Same error every time.
I've tried both Kubuntu 24.04 and Lubuntu 24.04 in VirtualBox, and they both have this same problem. I even tried Kubuntu 24.04 in my actual PC in a spare SSD, and same story.
I used these exact steps in Lubuntu 22.04 before and it worked just fine. Is it a known bug in the new 24.04 LTS?
UPDATE: In case its useful, here are a couple of screenshot comparisons from VirtualBox between Lubuntu 22.04.4 and Lubuntu 24.04 installation.
Lubuntu 22.04 (works):


Lubuntu 24.04 (doesn't work):


UPDATE 2: I tried selecting the erase whole drive option and encrypt from there, and that seems to be working. I tried both Kubuntu 24.04 and Lubuntu 24.04 in VirtualBox, and they both seem to be working as expected. Encrypting whole drive of course lacks the flexibility of manual partitioning.

What language are you using? what keyboard? and did you use the same encryption key in 22.04 & 24.04?  (mainly keys interest me; as the live system is fully running and has adjusted to language (keyboard) setup, where as at decryption mode the language detail comes from your BIOS settings/defaults as the OS hasn't yet booted).  22.04 was available with two calamares versions so your detail there isn't complete (for comparison).

@guiverc I used en-US.utf8 with the default US layout, the same I used for 22.04. I don't have any reason to suspect the keyboard layout is the problem. Note, same problem happens in both VirtualBox and PC. I didn't use the same passphrase as 22.04, but again, that should never be an issue. In VirtualBox, I even tried very simple passphrases like asdfasdf for testing, same thing. I don't know about the different calamares versions in 22.04, but I think I last installed 22.04.4 like this and it worked. Is 24.04 working for you with the steps I mentioned?

@guiverc I just downloaded Lubuntu 22.04.4 ISO and tried the same steps in VirtualBox again for testing, and it works as before, but 24.04 doesn't. Please see the update in the question.

I concur that keyboard/language should not be a problem, it was only a problem where the machine BIOS was say english (or one-country and character set) and the installers chosen language differed using different characters; as the decryption keys were read by BIOS/firmware as initial decryption is before the OS has booted.  I suggest filing a bug report about this please. https://git.lubuntu.me/lubuntu-wiki/wiki/wiki/Bugs or https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs  (ie. ubuntu-bug calamares) and we'll look at it.

@guiverc Thanks. Bug report submitted: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/calamares/+bug/2064909

ack... I saw (and have replied requesting an apport-collect be performed) that bug report before I came here.  Thanks for filing, and helping to make our Ubuntu (Lubuntu/Kubuntu/Ubuntu.Unity) systems better  (I'm betting you'd experience the same with Ubuntu.Unity thus my inclusion of it).  It's the install report I'm wanting to look at mostly, and your not using ubuntu-bug meant I have no ISO/install-report/etc details (the apport-collect after install failure will cause this to be uploaded).

Comment #24 by Aaron Rainbolt (arraybolt3) on this bug report clarified it:

It looks like you don't have a separate /boot partition being created?
All Ubuntu flavors use Canonical's build of GRUB (naturally), and
Canonical explicitly does not support /boot being located on an
encrypted partition. It actually creates additional security risks
to do so as Canonical doesn't test the code that handles encrypted
/boot.
Most likely what broke this is we changed from LUKS1 to LUKS2 in
Lubuntu to increase security. I do not believe GRUB supports LUKS2. As
encrypted /boot is not supported, and as there are security concerns
when using LUKS1, I don't think we probably should fall back to LUKS1.
If you're really determined to install with /boot on an encrypted
partition despite the fact that this is dangerous, try running sudo nano /etc/calamares/modules/partition.conf, and change
luksGeneration: luks2 to luksGeneration: luks1. Then try
installing with one big encrypted partition again. Again, this is
dangerous, and also it has a good chance of breaking if you use a
keyboard layout other than US.
Hope this is helpful!


Just as an FYI... But if you're interested in reading discussion around issue (between Aaron & Walter; both Lubuntu developers) see https://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2024/05/08/%23lubuntu-devel.html

A doc on this was created (after this question) and can be found here - https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/encrypted-boot-install-q-a-format/4891
